# php array page system, not working

Tags: php, arrays

So I'm working on setting up my first "fancy" page system, and I have run into a problem. I use the code seen below, and it loads the "profile" page without any problems, and the default page works fine too. However the other two pages does not show at all, and I can't seem to request them in the URL eighter. All the files are there tho. Any help here will be much appreciated! :)

```
if(isset($_SESSION['user_id'])){
    require('user.php');
    $player = new user($_SESSION['user_id'], $database);

    $default_page = 'profile';
    $pages = array(
        'profile' => array(
            'name' => 'Profile',
            'file' => 'profile.php',
            'function' => 'profile',
            ),
        'create_monster' => array(
            'name' => 'Create Monster',
            'file' => 'monsterPages.php',
            'function' => 'createMonster',
            ),
        'create_attack' => array(
            'name' => 'Create Attack',
            'file' => 'attackPages.php',
            'function' => 'createAttack',
        ),
    );

    if(!empty($_GET['page'])){
        $page = strtolower(trim($_GET['page']));

        if(isset($pages[$page])){
            require($pages[$page]['file']);
            echo "<p class='pageTitle'>" . $pages[$page]['name'] . "</p>";
            $pages[$page]['function']();
    }
    else{
            require($pages[$default_page]['file']);
            echo "<p class='pageTitle'>" . $pages[$default_page]['name'] . "</p>";
            $pages[$default_page]['function']();
    }
}
else{
    require($pages[$default_page]['file']);
    echo "<p class='pageTitle'>" . $pages[$default_page]['name'] . "</p>";
    $pages[$default_page]['function']();    
    }

}
```

Comment: how did you call `Create Monster` page? is `monsterPages.php` in the same directory of `profile.php`? have you enabled `display_errors` with `error_reporting(-1); ini_set('display_errors', 1);`?

Comment: Yes, the monsterPages.php are located in the same directory as profile.php. I have not played around with the error_reporting tho. I will read up on how to use it propperly. Thank you for your input! :)

Comment: can you add var_dump($_SESSION['user_id']) as the very 1st line, and tell us what it prints? I guess you don't start the session...

Comment: It is set, but it printed out,  string(1) "1". Thanks anyway! :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You've got some redundancy in your code.  You could abbreviate it.

```
$page = isset($_GET['page']) ? $_GET['page'] : $default_page;

// You should check that the page exists here.

require($pages[$page]['file']);
echo "<p class='pageTitle'>" . $pages[$page]['name'] . "</p>";
$pages[$page]['function']();
```

I suggest you place the page loading code in a function.  I've created a simple class here:

```
<?php

$pages = array(
    'profile' => array(
        'name' => 'Profile',
        'file' => 'profile.php',
        'function' => 'profile',
        ),
    'create_monster' => array(
        'name' => 'Create Monster',
        'file' => 'monsterPages.php',
        'function' => 'createMonster',
        ),
    'create_attack' => array(
        'name' => 'Create Attack',
        'file' => 'attackPages.php',
        'function' => 'createAttack',
    ),
);


class PageLoader
{

    public $pages;
    public $base_path;

    public function __construct($pages, $base_path)
    {
        $this->pages = $pages;
        $this->base_path = $base_path;
    }

    public function run($name) {
        if(! isset($this->pages[$name])) {
            throw new Exception('Page not found');
        } 

        $path = $this->base_path . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR . $this->pages[$name]['file']; 
        $func = $this->pages[$name]['function'];

        require_once $path;
        call_user_func($func);
    }

}


$page = isset($_GET['page']) ? $_GET['page'] : 'profile'; // If no page given default to profile.

$loader = new PageLoader($pages, '/tmp');
$loader->run($page);
```

Comment: Thanks man, i will play around with this and see if i can get it to work! :)

Comment: i fail to get this to work, its a new way to load pages for me, and im just like a week or two into coding. Even tho it looks more clean and i feel like i understand it. Im just to rookie to get it working. Thanks alot for taking your time to write it for me, i appreciate the effort! :)

Comment: Wow, typos can be hard to spot after this many hours! Sorry, your code works just fine! However i still have the same problem! :/ It stills only loads my profile.php nomatter what page i request in the search fiel on my site.

Comment: You trigger this script with a form?  Perhaps your form has a POST method instead of a GET method.  That could explain why you were having problems.  You did say you tested the URL manually?  Try adding the following to the url:  `?page=create_attack`, that works for me.

Comment: Progrock, you managed to guide me very well with your posts. They are straight forward, and so easy that even i as a new programer can follow a direction you point me in. Everything is now working, and im very happy with what i have created now! Thank you sir for helping me out with this last error of mine! Your help and time has been much appreciated, have a great day! :)

Comment: Great.  Nice to know I was of help.

Answer (score 0):

Before you can use $_SESSION, you need to start the session:

```
session_start(); # this should be the very 1st line in your php
if(isset($_SESSION['user_id'])){
    // ...
}
else{
    require($pages[$default_page]['file']);
    echo "<p class='pageTitle'>" . $pages[$default_page]['name'] . "</p>";
    $pages[$default_page]['function']();
    }
}
```

and make sure that `$pages[$default_page]['function']();` sets `$_SESSION['user_id']`

Comment: Yeah i does set a session, and my very first line of code is session_start(); The index.php is over 100 rows of code, so i just grabed the part where the pages are called and set.